# How To Create a Simple Universal Image Loader via URL(Only one image)

Tags: android

I Done this much but don't Know why the image does't desplay. And also told me that after this How Can i put those images into grid views.)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    bitmap=getBitmapFromURL("http://cs596.vk.me/u78792285/a_98dc2d1e.jpg");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src)
    {
    try {
    URL url=new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
    }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Fix the formatting so I can clearly see your code...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, both httpUrlConnection and updating your image into the image view need to be in a thread or a runnable.

note how I changed your onCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setBitmapFromURL("http://cs596.vk.me/u78792285/a_98dc2d1e.jpg");
    }

 public void setBitmapFromURL(String src)
 {
    try 
    {
       new Thread(new Runnable() 
       {
           public void run() 
           {
              URL url=new URL(src);
              HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              connection.setDoInput(true);
              connection.connect();
              InputStream input=connection.getInputStream();
              Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

              if(bitmap!=null)
              {
                try
                {
                  final Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                  {   
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                      imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }         
                  });
                }
                catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
                {
                }
             }
           }
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```